# Java Hibernate NamedQuery resultTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

i have this query with `NamedQuery` using `Hibernate` this is my sample code.

`NamedQuery`

```
@NamedQuery(name="com.company.generic.model.Student.getByID()",query="select name from com.company.generic.model.Student where id=:id")
```

`Java Code`

```
private Student getStudentNameById(Integer id)
{
    final Session session = ....
    final Query query = session.getNamedQuery("com.company.generic.model.Student.getByID()")
    .setParameter("id",id)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));
    final Student student = (Student)query.uniqueResult();
    return student;
}
```

when the query returns all the columns the `resultTransformer`works OK but when i return only a few columns returns

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for 0 on class com.company.generic.model.Student
```

my questions are

1). why works with all columns but not working with a few or only a column.

2). which is the diff between namedQuery and Criteria using resultTransformer should namedQuery have setProjection?

3). must i write my own transformer? any workaround...?

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**question #1:**
Most probably you need to add alias to `name` field in select list

```
select s.name as name from com.company.generic.model.Student s where s.id=:id
```

so Hibernate can find the setName(String) method in `Student.class`.
Using criteria the equivalent is

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class)
 .add(Restrictions.eq("id",id))
 .setProjection(Projections.property("name").as("name"))
 .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));
```

**question #2:**
Named query select list is the projection.

**question #3:** 
see answers above

Comment: yep the problem was i can only use namedQueries in this case.. but your solution works using ALIAS.. thanks a lot.